# Set filename for file stored on S3

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5.6, maatwebsite-excel

I am using [this package](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/) to export my collections to excel (CSV):

I use the following code to store it on s3:

```
$path = Carbon::now()->toDateString() . '/' . bin2hex(random_bytes(32)) . '.csv';
(new BillsExport($bills))->store($path, 's3', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::CSV);
```

Now for the filename I'm using a random 32 length guid.  However when they download the file I want the actual name of the file to be displayed like `bills.csv` instead of `4f68481f5a8c09b7823c042d7d2fca457e297839d31e33fcefd09056f86cce00.csv`

I would like to know if that is possible and how I can achieve this with laravel using S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with `response()->download()`. For example:

```
return response()->download($path, 'bills.csv', $headers);
```

For more information, read the documentation on [HTTP Responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#file-downloads).